# Issue with switching from intel to nvidia after suspend

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 19.04

I just wanted to know if anyone ever had the same bug than I submitted : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1827446

TL;DR Suspend while being on intel, then waking up, then switch to nvidia. Ubuntu is unable to access nvidia anymore.

Also, I am wondering if anyone in the community has managed to resolve the issue with a workaround or has anyone found a way to make it work with some kernel parameters?